# Unity al moverse la camara no me funciona el movimiento de la espada

Tags: unity, game, aplicación-movil

He hecho un script en el que con la pantalla tactil puedes mover una espada. El problema es que cuando la camara se mueve en el eje z, el movimiento de la espada aumenta muchisimo. Os paso el codigo:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // get first touch since touch count is greater than zero

            Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x * changeSpeedX, touch.position.y * changeSpeedZ, transform.position.z));

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                    deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.z;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    Vector3 touchedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x * changeSpeedX, touch.position.y * changeSpeedZ, transform.position.z));
                    touchedPos = new Vector3(touchedPos.x - deltaX, transform.position.y, touchedPos.y - deltaY);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
                    break;
            }
```